# JQuery: How to select element with name+variable?

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out... :-(
How can I select an element with a name + variable (corresponding id of the note)

HTMl:

```
<div class="editable" id="tiny_12">blablabla</div>
<input type="button" class="bouton_save_ajax" id="sauver_billet_html_12">

<div class="editable" id="tiny_13">blablabla</div>
<input type="button" class="bouton_save_ajax" id="sauver_billet_html_13">

<div class="editable" id="tiny_14">blablabla</div>
<input type="button" class="bouton_save_ajax" id="sauver_billet_html_14">

...
...
```

And javascript (Jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#sauver_billet_html_12").click(function (event) {

        var bufferId = {};
        bufferId['html'] = $("#tiny_12").html();
        // bufferId['id'] = 12;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_save_post",
            data: bufferId,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(event.target.id);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do it just the way you're doing it. I don't see anything wrong with your code, and i don't see you using a variable to select anything.

Comment: That or we don't understand your question.

Comment: $("[name='value']") is this what you want.

Comment: @seanxiaoxiao, that's what I thought at first, but none of his elements has a name attribute.

Comment: I am not sure why you need a name attr to select. But why don't you considering using id or class for selector. It works out the same result.

Comment: I've edited, it wasn't clear enough: The divs are generated with tiny_xx (where xx is an id generated), same id than the button (sauver_billet_html_xx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like that:

[http://jsfiddle.net/WHL2P/1](http://jsfiddle.net/WHL2P/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[id^=sauver_billet_html_]").click(function (event) { 
        var buffer = {};
        buffer.id = this.id.split('_').pop();
        buffer.html = $("#tiny_"+buffer.id).html();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_save_post",
            data: buffer,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(event.target.id);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Improve performance by using the tag name to restrict the query: `$('input[id^=sauver_billet_html_]')`.

Comment: How can I get the variable from my php file (url:ajax_save_post)? Before I get them with $_POST[id] and $_POST[html], but now I can't get anything... :-(

Comment: Updated answer:: $_POST['id'] & $_POST['html'] should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, nothing is returned with $_POST['id']

Comment: That's ok, you put a cap I in 'Id', that's why it didn't worked! It's ok, I can get all elements, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: No one is answering my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031589/add-tinymce-for-new-element-loaded-dynamicaly
Any help please?