# add tinymce for new element loaded dynamicaly

Tags: tinymce

My page is lodaed with 5 divs which can be edited by Tinymce inline editor. I've a peace of Jquery loding 5 new ones by clicking on a button (so dynamicaly). But of course the new ones are not affected by Tinymce, as the init has already been loaded... How can I manage to activate tinymce for new divs please?

My HTML :

```
<div id=\"billetdroit\">
            <div id=\"divtitre\"><h1 class=\"editable\">blablabla</h1></div>
        <div class=\"editable\" id=\"tiny_01\">blablabla2</div>
        </div>
<div id=\"billetdroit\">
                <div id=\"divtitre\"><h1 class=\"editable\">blablabla</h1></div>
            <div class=\"editable\" id=\"tiny_02\">blablabla2</div>
            </div>
<div id=\"billetdroit\">
                <div id=\"divtitre\"><h1 class=\"editable\">blablabla</h1></div>
            <div class=\"editable\" id=\"tiny_03\">blablabla2</div>
            </div>

...
...
```

And a button: when you click, it make appears 5 more divs "billetdroit" dynamicaly

My tinymce init:

```
tinymce.init({
                    selector: "textarea",
                    language: 'fr_FR',
                    image_advtab: true,
                    menubar:false,
                    forced_root_block: false,
                    plugins: ["link","code","media","image","textcolor", "emoticons"],
                    toolbar: "bold italic forecolor backcolor alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify link unlink image media emoticons"
                 });
                 tinymce.init({
                    selector: "h1.editable",
                    language: 'fr_FR',
                    inline: true,
                    toolbar: "undo redo",
                    menubar: false
                });

                tinymce.init({
                    selector: "div.editable",
                    language: 'fr_FR',
                    image_advtab: true,
                    menubar:false,
                    inline: true,
                    forced_root_block: false,
                    plugins: ["link","code","media","image","textcolor", "emoticons"],
                    toolbar: "bold italic forecolor backcolor alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify link unlink image media emoticons"
                });
```

Any solution?
Thanks

EDIT:

I tryied that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var track_click = 1; //track user click on "load more" button, righ now it is 0 click

    var total_pages = Globals.total_pages;

//    $('#results').load("loadmore.php", {'page':track_click}, function() {track_click++;}); //initial data to load


    $(".load_more").click(function (e) { //user clicks on button

        $(this).hide(); //hide load more button on click
        $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

        if(track_click <= total_pages) //user click number is still less than total pages
        {
            //post page number and load returned data into result element
            $.post('loadmore.php',{'page': track_click}, function(data) {

                $(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button

                $("#results").append(data); //append data received from server

                //scroll page smoothly to button id
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#load_more_button").offset().top}, 500);

                //hide loading image
                $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                track_click++; //user click increment on load button

            }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?
                alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                $(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button
                $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received
            });


            if(track_click >= total_pages-1) //compare user click with page number
            {
                //reached end of the page yet? disable load button
                $(".load_more").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
         }
         $.getScript('include/tinymce/tinymce.min.js', function() {
            tinymce.init({
                    selector: "textarea",
                    language: 'fr_FR',
                    image_advtab: true,
                    menubar:false,
                    forced_root_block: false,
                    plugins: ["link","code","media","image","textcolor", "emoticons"],
                    toolbar: "bold italic forecolor backcolor alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify link unlink image media emoticons"
                 });
                 tinymce.init({
                    selector: "h1.editable",
                    language: 'fr_FR',
                    inline: true,
                    toolbar: "undo redo",
                    menubar: false
                });

                tinymce.init({
                    selector: "div.editable",
                    language: 'fr_FR',
                    image_advtab: true,
                    menubar:false,
                    inline: true,
                    forced_root_block: false,
                    plugins: ["link","code","media","image","textcolor", "emoticons"],
                    toolbar: "bold italic forecolor backcolor alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify link unlink image media emoticons"
                });
            });

        });
});
```

But without success...

Comment: why you don't just recall tinymce init on new added element?!

Comment: That's what I would like... But how please?

Comment: The same way you did it for static element, just recall it inside your click button handler after these elements have been added

Comment: Could you gime the exact syntaxe please?

Comment: Firstly, IDs must be unique on context page! Your code here is not valid, fix this or many things won't work. Secondly, try yourself and tell me after where are you stuck. But i hate tinymce, i don't use it and don't want to.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not enough advanced in javascript to have only one idea how to do that :-(

Comment: I tryied that (see edit) but nothing happend

Comment: I repeat my self but are you using unique IDs? More than one element with id 'billetdroit' is not valid! But, regarding your problem, you have to set option selector of tinymce according to which elements you have added. And please remember, i'm not from tinymce support, i don't want to/cannot lose time on problems which are not mine.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I don't disturb you any more.

Comment: Anyone else can help me regarding this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to init tinymce editors:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, 'your_div_id');
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made it an other way: I put tinymceinit() after each new div generated. It works...